# Abbyy Flexicapture - Dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, combobox, abbyy

I am trying to create a dropdown in AbyyFlexicapture.
The dropdown should be filled from database (i have external DLL ready to do the job) or with fixed values. The problem is I cant find the appropriate element for the job. All i found (the closest) was checkbox group, but I dont know how to use it (add items programaticaly). The documentation on this is very poor ...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Figured it out. You just push data to textbox with query and it gets auto-converted to dropdown. But theres no way (at least known to me) how to set up default selection...

Comment: I realize this is an ancient posting, but it would be helpful to know which version of FlexiCapture. I'm guessing FC9.0 since the posting date is November of 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. You just push data to textbox with query and it gets auto-converted to dropdown. But theres no way (at least known to me) how to set up default selection...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the IField.Suggest() method.